# How to cut a dendrogram and represent on a geographic map

Tags: matlab

I would like know if there are any tools/commands in MATLAB or any other software that helps to cut the dendrogram (where points represent states) at a certain height and represent it in a geographical map like the one in the below images.

[image]    [image]

Could you please let me know if there is any better way to do it

Thank you.

Comment: Could you give a bit more information about what you mean with "cut the dendrogram at a certain height" - and maybe give an example of the kind of data you are representing?

Comment: Sure. I am working on analysing the statistics of the US states and have generated the average linkage and from that generate the dendrogram. I would like to see how the clusters look when mapped on the states,for which I am thinking on cutting the dendrogram in order to represent on the map,similar to the one shown in the image. Does this information helps.Do let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: I believe you can easily do it with [Mapping Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/mapping/). Do you have it?

Comment: I may have to buy it.But could you give me a rough idea or sequence of commands to get this result assuming that I have the following commands
t2=linkage(squareform(t1),'average')
[H,T]=dendrogram(t2,0,'colorthreshold',0.5)
How to extract the dendrogram locations,labels,color and how to map it on the map.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can draw polar dendrogram (as on your example) with File Exchange submission - [Draw a Polar Dendrogram](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21983-draw-a-polar-dendrogram).

To apply threshold to distance between nodes and get the cluster data you can use [CLUSTER](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/cluster.html) or [CLUSTERDATA](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/clusterdata.html) function.

Then you can use [USAMAP](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/usamap.html) function from Mapping Toolbox to draw the states and apply colors based on your clusters. See the example 3 in the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/usamap.html#f15-776823).

Comment: Oh great!!I will try this out.So far, I could only get the polar dendrogram and couldnt not proceed as I was not sure on how to get the cluster information with colors and how to use this on a map.
I will get the Mapping Toolbox, try out the steps suggested and shall update with the results.
Thank you. Really appreciate your help.